# How call method from Fragment in Activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a class MainActivity with three fragments.

Fragment Two uses a WebView.
I want to create a method `Webview.reaload()` in Fragment Two
and call this method from MainActivity. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With getActivity() you will get the activity instance, cast it to your activity name and call function from fragments. Assuming activity name as MainActivity

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).myFuncInActivity():
```

Comment: can set an example, if not difficult

Comment: Because i am recrut in here

Comment: You do not need to show a great example of just how to transfer the method and remove it

Comment: I don't get you dude

Answer (score 0):

**Interfaces** work well will this kind of communication.

Check out this guide:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: Did you go to the website? there is a perfect example there. Look under the "**Creating event callbacks to the activity**" heading. There is a great simple example.

Comment: Also, at the bottom of the website page (developer.android.com) there is a selector to change which language is displayed. If your language is available, it would be a good idea to change that.

Comment: Yes sir i went in web site

Comment: Alright man, I'm not going to copy and paste from the developer website, just go there and start reading.

Comment: Can you show me here how i create method in fragment 2 i need method webview reload  and trasnfer in main activity .and in main activity remove it i need very esy example , please sir.

Comment: Seriously, I got downvoted for this? Someone does not know how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Alright, no need to downvote me to oblivion for it. I thought that simply stating that **Interfaces** would have answered his question in an acceptable manner, and the link was only provided as additional documentation in case he needed it. He provided no code for me to make an example of. I have seen plenty of questions on SO that were answered in the same manner as mine.